# Plenty of space on page but can't make figures bigger

Tags: floats

I am trying to put two figures on one page in latex, without using minipage. But the second figure is moved to the next page at a certain size, even though there is plenty of white space left on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Use subfigures..? (e.g., try `texdoc subfigure`)  Without a minimal example to look at, it is hard (for me) to give useful advice.

Comment: Are they subfigures or seperate ones? In what way are you trying to  place those figures? Using `picture` environment or `figure` environment?

Comment: or else the `subcaption` package

Answer (score 7):

The fraction of the page that may be used for figures is by default not the full page it is controlled by various parameters, notably `\topfraction` You can set these parameters or you could use an optional parameter `\begin{figure}[!tbp]` where the `!` tells LaTeX to ignore the size constraints.

Comment: I'd add that `\topfraction` (AFAIK) only applies to "mixed" pages (running text plus floats), not to "exclusive" float pages.

Comment: Yes there are several parameters but I didn't want to mention them all `\floatpagefraction`  acts on float pages, but also the integer (count) parameters. `!` ignores them all anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Without a minimal example one can't be sure, but you may put two separate graphics and their respective captions into a single `figure` (floating)  environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text. See also figures~\ref{fig:x} and~\ref{fig:y}.

\begin{figure}
\centering

\rule{1cm}{15cm}% placeholder for first graphic
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:x}

\vspace{\floatsep}

\rule{5cm}{1cm}% placeholder for second graphic
\caption{Another figure}\label{fig:y}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```